# Navigation bar back button colour not working in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, back-button

In my app, I have given navigation bar back button colour as red. Both arrow and text works finely with iPhone in all screens. But in iPad it works correctly only for home screen. When I enter inside any of the other view controllers, my navigation back text is in red colour but back button arrow becomes grey colour. Here is my code,

```
func setup() {
    self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: CGFloat(22.0))!
    ]
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red

//        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(132.0 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(204.0 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(90.0 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))

    // Draw a bottom border
    let bottomBorderHeight = 3 / UIScreen.main.scale
    let bottomBorder = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(self.navigationBar.frame.size.height-bottomBorderHeight), width: CGFloat(self.view.bounds.width), height: CGFloat(bottomBorderHeight)))
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(0 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(97 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(56 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    self.navigationBar.addSubview(bottomBorder)
}
```

Tried barTintcolor, appearance, bar style etc..but nothing works. Any idea? TIA.

Comment: Does `tintAdjustmentMode` helps?

Comment: when will you call this method func setup() ?

Comment: try to replace/add  these line with yours         UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue

Comment: am calling this method in viewDidLoad. And the above code didn't work. Still comes in grey colour.

Comment: did you show my answer @user579911

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, try this line to change back button color change

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

I hope it's work for you,